# Angular 4 Universal Build Throws Memory Limit Error

Tags: angular

I am trying to do my big angular 4 app to make universal build but after reaching 90% of process it throws below error

Please help me out for this, I also use --max_new_space_size but it doesn't work at all same error occurs again and again

Angular CLI : 1.4.4

Node : 8.9.4

```html
Security context: 0x2189632d <JSObject>
    1: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [native array.js:~95] [pc=0x3bb15e9b](this=0x28a841a1 <undefined>,p=0x2c9cc3e9 <JSArray[5865]>,q=5865,E=0x28a84209 <true>,A=0x28a84279 <String[0]: >,z=0x28a84249 <false>)
    2: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:~120] [pc=0x82167caf](this=0x28a841a1 <undefined>,p=0x2c9cc3e9 <JSArray[5865]>,q=5865,A=0x28a84279 <String[0]: >,z=0x28a84249 <false>)
    3: InnerArrayJoin(aka Inner...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [@angular/cli]
 2: 0x8dfe196 [@angular/cli]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [@angular/cli]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [@angular/cli]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [@angular/cli]
 6: v8::internal::Runtime_StringBuilderConcat(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [@angular/cli]
```

Comment: Can you show the command line you tried with the extra size  option?

Comment: node --max_old_space_size=2048  my-node-script.js

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max_old_space_size` and setting the size in MB

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build ...
```

Comment: I have tried it but every time I got error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: @Kishan Segfault is a different issue. Your OS is 64bit, right? And if you try with a smaller value, do you still get memory error or do you get segmentation fault?

Comment: My Ubuntu OS is 32-bit and I have also tried it out in 64 bit OS on other PC but I am still finding same problem.

Comment: So you get a `segmentation fault` on your 64 machine too, with smaller values?

Comment: yes I am getting same error on 64 bit, and what you mean by smaller values?

Comment: Smaller than 4096, which is actually 4GB of memory. The original issue you have  is that there is not enough memory allocated to the process. This occurs during processing. The new issue, when trying to fix the first one with the setting I indicated, is that it cannot allocate enough memory from the start

Comment: Thanks for your clarification but I have tried out 2,3,4 and even more than 4 GB but I get same error each time. Do you know any tracking command of universal build so we can see each process in detail and find out where process is stopped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168539/discussion-between-david-and-kishan).

Answer (score 0):

try to use below command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=12388
 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note:
I "successfully" created this kind of error with creating accidentally a loop in components. I mean, create two components A, and B, and in HTML template of A there is a B component, and in HTML template B there is an A component.
The angular-cli just compiled it without error, but my page just did not showed anything but sigsegv error. Dev.console was detached, and asked for page update. No info about the cause of error :(.